# R chron times() function won't work

Tags: r, chron

I'm trying to convert a time to seconds since midnight.  I'm having a hard time getting the times() function from the chron package to work.  Here's how I'm using it:

```
> library(chron)
> 24 * 24 * 60 * (times(50))
Error in 24 * 24 * 60 * (times(50)) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
> 
>  
> library(chron)
> 24 * 24 * 60  times(5000)
Error: unexpected symbol in "24 * 24 * 60  times"
```

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.14.0 (2011-10-31)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RODBC_1.3-3        nnet_7.3-1         doSNOW_1.0.3       foreach_1.3.0     
[5] codetools_0.2-8    iterators_1.0.3    snow_0.3-7         randomForest_4.6-2
[9] chron_2.3-42      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.14.0
```

UPDATE 2 :

```
> find("times")
[1] "package:foreach" "package:chron"  
> times
function (n) 
{
    if (!is.numeric(n) || length(n) != 1) 
        stop("n must be a numeric value")
    foreach(icount(n), .combine = "c")
}
<environment: namespace:foreach>
```

UPDATE 3:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.14.0 (2011-10-31)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] chron_2.3-42
> find("times")
[1] "package:chron"
> 24 * 24 * 60 * (times * (50))
Error in times * (50) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Comment: I get the same result as Josh. You may need to update R and `update.packages` with check.built=TRUE. At a minimum you need to provide `sessionInfo()`

Comment: The first version, `24 * 24 * 60 * (times(50))`, works just fine for me, returning `[1] 1728000` etc... Have you tried `find("times")`, or just typing `times` to confirm that R is finding the function that you expect, from `"package:chron"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `package:foreach` also contains a function named `times`. And because it appears before `package:chron` on your search path, it 'masks' the `times` function that you actually want.

In other words, when R performs its dynamic search for the symbol `times`, it finds a match (the wrong one in this case) before it gets to the one associated with the function you're intending it to find.

You can see this by starting a fresh R session, and then typing:

```
> library(chron)
> library(foreach)
Loading required package: iterators
Loading required package: codetools
foreach: simple, scalable parallel programming from Revolution Analytics
Use Revolution R for scalability, fault tolerance and more.
http://www.revolutionanalytics.com

Attaching package: ‘foreach’

The following object(s) are masked from ‘package:chron’:

    times
```

If you *do* need both packages attached, you can ensure that you get the right version of `times()` by either: reversing the order in which the packages are attached (OK but not great); or (better) explicitly specifying which function you want by typing `chron::times`, as in:

```
24 * 24 * 60 * (chron::times(50))
```

Comment: chron::times() did it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Bravo for find("function-name").